# Why is my VB program throwing an exception complaining that a OleDbDataReader is closed, when it should absolutely be open?

Tags: vb.net, oledb, sqlbulkcopy

I am trying to use OleDB and SQLBulkCopy to pull data off an excel spreadsheet, into an SQL database. When I try and run my code, I get the following exception, triggered by 
 "bulkCopy.WriteToServer(objDR)" (which is also described in the question title): [exception data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bHpY.png)

OleDB successfully reads the excel sheet which is then populated properly in the DataGridView I created within a WinForm for debugging purposes.

Below is a snippet of the relevant code.

```
Dim ExcelConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\damon\Everyone\sheet1erictest.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes""")
    ExcelConnection.Open()
    Dim sheet As String = "Sheet5$"
    Dim expr As String = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheet + "]"

    Dim objCmdSelect As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(expr, ExcelConnection)
    Dim objDR As OleDbDataReader

    Dim SQLconn As New SqlConnection()
    Dim ConnString As String = "SERVER=SqlDEV;DATABASE=Freight;Integrated Security=True"
    SQLconn.ConnectionString = ConnString
    SQLconn.Open()


    Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(SQLconn)
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.test"

        Try

            objDR = objCmdSelect.ExecuteReader

            Dim dt = New DataTable()
            dt.Load(objDR)
            DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
            DataGridView1.Refresh()
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(objDR)

            objDR.Close()
            SQLconn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: `ExcelConnection.Open()` looks like it's never closed.  If your code throws an exception, SQLconn won't close either.  Always favor the Using-Block on disposable objects.  Which line is actually throwing the exception?

Comment: @LarsTech I went ahead and added the line to close the ExcelConnection at the end of the using block; expectedly did not fix the error. I'm a bit confused as to how using a second using-block would mitigate the issue of the SQLconn not closing.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?  You don't have SQLconn in a using block, and if `bulkCopy.WriteToServer(objDR)` throws an exception, it will skip the `SQLconn.Close()` line.  Using-blocks will always dispose their object, even when an exception is thrown.

Comment: @LarsTech That makes sense! So I should have three using blocks for objDR, SqlConn (which I imagine is the same as having the using block for the SqlBulkCopy which holds this), and ExcelConnection?

                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(objDR)
is what is triggering the exception.

Comment: I would get rid of that `Dim dt = New DataTable()` line and the DataGridView stuff and just run the `bulkCopy.WriteToServer(objDR)`  Your objDR is already being used by the DataTable, so don't do that.

Comment: @LarsTech You just solved my issue. Was not aware binding the reader to the datatable would make it unavailable for other purposes. Thanks so much. :)

Feel free to write an answer so I can give you your well deserved reputation.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would also put the `using` block inside the `try` instead of the other way around.  As it is, if the `using` statement threw an error, you wouldn't catch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reader object is being used by the DataTable, so comment out those lines and run them separately later with a new instance:

```vb
objDR = objCmdSelect.ExecuteReader

'Dim dt = New DataTable()
'dt.Load(objDR)
'DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
'DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
'DataGridView1.Refresh()
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(objDR)
```